# How to Display Data According to Different Different category on Page in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have multiple category store in my database, and i am developing a blog website, I want to display front page according to my requirement.
There are lots of section available on front page and each section have different category, so data will be display according to category. Please let me know how i can do this.

Here are my views.py file....

```
def article_list(request):
category = Category.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
blog = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[0:5]
return render(request, 'article/index.html',
              {'category': category, 'blog': blog})
```

and here are my one section on index.html file...i want to get data from `business` category(this is store in my database) in this section. But i am getting all posts from database, please let me know how i can change in my `for loop` so that data will be display from `business` category.

```
<ul class="list-posts">
                                        {% for i in blog %}
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="/media/{{i.image}}" alt="">
                                            <div class="post-content">
                                                <h2><a href="single-post.html">{{i.name}}</a></h2>
                                                <ul class="post-tags">
                                                    <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{{i.created_at}}</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted how your models are declared, so I'm assuming something like this:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

You can limit the posts with an `{% if %}` tag in your template:

```html
<ul class="list-posts">
    {% for post in blog %}
    {% if post.category.name == 'business' %}
    <li>
        <img src="/media/{{ post.image }}" alt="">
        <div class="post-content">
            <h2><a href="single-post.html">{{ post.name }}</a></h2>
            <ul class="post-tags">
                <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{{ post.created_at }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```